# Why map in OSM not display in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I already add this library in libs directory
osmdroid jar file.
slf4j jar file.

I followed tutorial in https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2521
but the map didnt show, i dont know whats happening
[image]

This is my MainAcitvity.java

```
package com.example.pc_parinussa.osm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MapView         mMapView;
    private MapController   mMapController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = (MapController) mMapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint gPt = new GeoPoint(51500000, -150000);
        mMapController.setCenter(gPt);
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapview">
    </org.osmdroid.views.MapView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pc_parinussa.osm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: You can remove `compile files('libs/` by the way... You already compile that

Comment: So it is just compile osmodroid?

Comment: No, I'm saying that `compile fileTree(` is already grabbing all the jar files, so I you didn't need to add that additional line for your JAR file

Comment: Consider updating your question. "not display in android studio?" is an IDE problem, however everything else in your question indicates that the map isn't working on device.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't set your user agent. Try setting it via:

`Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(...)`

e.g.:

`Configuration.getInstance().setUserAgentValue(getPackageName())`

Comment: Wheere i set the user agent? Is it in MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, set it before creating your `MapView` object.

Comment: getInstance() in Configuration show 'cannot resolve symbol'. What happen?

Comment: That article is very old. Not sure why anyone would want to use an non-authoritative source for using a library. I'm willing to be that @JoshParinussa is using a very old version of osmdroid.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to `onCreate()`

```
getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have no idea why, but that was indeed the missing piece after external storage permissions were granted.

Answer (score 0):

OSM requires the access to the external storage of your phone.

First, add these permissions in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Second, if your SDK version is later than 23, the user has to allow the permission manually. Then **also** add the following codes in your activity. It is better that this activity is launched before the activity with OSM; otherwise, at the first time to start the App, you still cannot see the map - you can only see the map when you restart the App.

**Note: There codes should be written before "setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);"**

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
             && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
  } 

 setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name);
```

See the picture of the box requiring your permission when you start the App at the first time:

[Permission box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6KkG.png)